# Secure SSL Webservices under Glassfish

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, ejb, glassfish-3

Hello I'm deploying a webservice (ejb) under Glassfish, I just follow this steps without any result http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-api-for-xml-web-services/using-jax-ws-based-web-services-wit.html:
glassfish-ejb-jar.xml descriptor content:

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//
DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 EJB 3.1//EN" 
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-ejb-jar_3_1-1.dtd">
<glassfish-ejb-jar>
<enterprise-beans>
    <ejb>
        <ejb-name>Test</ejb-name>
        <webservice-endpoint>
            <port-component-name>Test</port-component-name>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </webservice-endpoint>
    </ejb>
</enterprise-beans>
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

When I try go to https://mysite.com/Test it shows a blank page, any idea?

Comment: Are you just expecting it to go over SSL or are you expecting SSL and some form of authentication? Also can you post the ejb Test code?